# Ada - Type conversion, exit when loop

Tags: loops, type-conversion, ada

Ada 2012.

I have this definition :

```
with Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions; use Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
package body Primes is
   function is_prime(n : Integer) return Boolean
   is
      i : Integer := 5;
   begin
      if n <= 3 then
         return n > 1;
      elsif n mod 2 = 0 or else n mod 3 = 0 then
         return false;
      else
         --for i in 5 .. Sqrt()n + 1 
         loop
            if n mod i = 0 or else n mod (i + 2) = 0 then
               return false;
            end if;
            exit when i >= Sqrt(n) + 1;
            i := i + 6;
         end loop;
         return true;
      end if;

   end is_prime;

end Primes;
```

That checks whether `n` is prime or not. The this is line:

```
exit when i >= Sqrt(n) + 1;
```

Provides errors

```
expected type "Standard.Float"
found type "Standard.Integer"
```

I've been trying to `Float'Value()` on all parts of the statement, but then I got some error regarding what I think is `exit when` type (String). Now I'm stuck at this thing and can't get it to compile. Everything else is fine and doesn't need to be reviewed.

The reason why I used `loop -> exit when -> end loop` is because **Ada** doesn't support For loop with a specified step like for example Java:

```
for (int i = 5; i < Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i +=6)
```

Comment: This algorithm finds both 5 and 7 to be non-prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simon's answer is a lot more efficient, but to demonstrate how you would do this the way you're trying to do it:

```
        exit when Float(i) >= Sqrt(Float(n)) + 1.0;
```

Ada simply does not automatically convert integers to floats the way some languages do.  (That also means it won't convert the integer literal `1` to a `Float` since a `Float` is needed for the predefined `+` operator on `Float`.  You could use a type conversion, `Float(1)`, instead of `1.0`.)

Also, if you do things this way, compute `Sqrt(Float(n))` outside the loop and save it in a variable (or something equivalent).  There's no point in calling `Sqrt` over and over on the same value inside the loop.  (Yeah, I know, someone will complain about premature optimization...)

**MORE:** This example shows how to achieve a type conversion.  `Float'Value` doesn't do anything like that.  If you look up "Value attribute" in the [RM Index](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-0-4.html), you'll see that the `'Value` attribute is a function that takes a `String` argument, and returns a number whose image is the String--i.e. it parses the string and returns a number, in this case a `Float`.

Comment: As for assigning computed value into a variable before loop - don't worry, I was going to do that (in fact I tried it before, but this is one of many possible things I've tried). That **MORE** really helped me out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The square-root function in `Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions` (of which `Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions` is an instantiation) is

```
function Sqrt (X : Float_Type'Base) return Float_Type’Base;
```

which only handles floating-point types.

You might be able to use

```
exit when i * i >= n;
```

(mind you, if `i * i` was equal to `n` then `n` wouldn’t be prime; some attention needed to this terminating condition, I think)

Comment: so basically what you're saying is that there is no other option to do this using `Sqrt`? That would be really odd.

Comment: Thank you both for valuable responses.